# How to dynamically add values to google geochart through mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I have to add dynamic data to google geochart through mysql or database so that when i update values from backend it automatically gets displayed on google geocharts functionality that i will embed using php language.
Can anyone please help me on this.
I have one refereence link: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you start developing the maps and php script, you just need to create a cicle where you include the data from the database.

I wont be very specific, but something like:

```
function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],

          <?php while () { ?>
          ['<?php echo $row['country']; ?>', <?php echo $row['value']; ?>],
          <?php } ?>

          ]);
```

Comment: This worked for me : <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT naition, COUNT( naition ) FROM survey GROUP BY userid LIMIT 0 , 30");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { //print_r($row); ?>
['<?php echo $row['naition']; ?>',<?php echo $row['COUNT( naition )']; ?>],
<?php } ?>                                                                Tahnks for the help